I get this error - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found. what can I do about it?
I'm working on a Flask project with SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL. When I try to run the Flask app, I encounter the following error:
Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path\to\project\app.py", line 8, in 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
File "path\to\virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 278, in init
self.init_app(app)
File "path\to\virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 374, in init_app
engines[key] = self._make_engine(key, options, app)
File "path\to\virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 665, in make_engine
return sa.engine_from_config(options, prefix="")
File "path\to\virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 820, in engine_from_config
return create_engine(url, **options)
File "path\to\virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 599, in create_engine
dbapi = dbapi_meth(**dbapi_args)
File "path\to\virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\psycopg2.py", line 690, in import_dbapi
import psycopg2
File "path\to\virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2_init.py", line 51, in 
from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
...
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.
Environment Details:
Python version: Python 3.13.0
Flask version: Flask 3.1.0
SQLAlchemy version: SQLAlchemy 2.0.36
psycopg2 version: psycopg2-binary : Version: 2.9.10
PostgreSQL version: psql (PostgreSQL) 17.2
OS: Windows 10 22H2
Steps I've Taken:

Installed psycopg2-binary instead of psycopg2 (tried both none of them worked)
Reinstalled Visual C++ Redistributable to the latest version
Added Path file in system environment for Postgresql/bin


See Add Python 3.13 packages for Windows.

Python 3.13 is not currently supported by psycopg2 and psycopg2-binary on Windows machine. Use Python 3.12 instead. See the available wheels for specific platforms on psycopg2-binary and psycopg2.
